# Insert statement not working in scandir

Tags: php, insert, scandir

I have a following query which is not working for a specific case.

```
function scantemp(){
  if ($dir = opendir('../themes/')) {
    $onlyfolder = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($files = readdir($dir))) {
      if (!in_array($files, $onlyfolder)) {
          $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `templates` (temp_loc) VALUES ('$files')");
      } 
    }
    closedir($dir);
  }
}
```

This code is scanning folders and inserting them to database but it is always inserting. I want to insert if folder does not exist. Please advise.

Comment: Perform a select query and insert if the record does not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose add a unique index by putting the following SQL.

> ALTER TABLE `templates` ADD UNIQUE (`temp_loc`)

after that if your record exists then insertion will not be occur. now use your code

```
function scantemp(){
 if ($dir = opendir('../themes/')) {
    $onlyfolder = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($files = readdir($dir))) {
        if (!in_array($files, $onlyfolder)) {
                $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `templates` (temp_loc) VALUES ('$files')");
        }   
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
}
```